# JPA EntityGraph, create subgraph of PluralAttribute programmably by using static MetaModel

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitygraph

When I have below entity.

```
@Entity
class Article {
  @OneToMany
  Set<Comment> comments;
}

@Entity
class Comment {
  @ManyToOne
  User author;
}
```

And create some view specification class using EntityGraph and static metamodel like below.

```
class ArticleViewSpec {

  /**
   * fetch comments and each of comment's author.
   */
  public static final Function<EntityManager, EntityGraph<Article>> DETAIL = em -> {
    EntityGraph<Article> graph = em.createEntityGraph(Article.class);

    Subgraph<Comment> sgComment = graph.addSubgraph(Article_.comments);

    sgComment.addAttributeNodes(Comment_.author);

    return graph;
  };
}
```

But above class can't be compiled, because expected type is not

```
Subgraph<Comment> sgComment = graph.addSubgraph(Article_.comments);
```

but

```
Subgraph<Set<Comment>> sgComment = graph.addSubgraph(Article_.comments);
```

This problem occurs when we have attribute that extends `javax.persistence.metamodel.PluralAttribute`.
 (e.g. SetAttribute, ListAttribute)

This behaviour is obviously from api spec.
`javax.persistence.EntityGraph#addSubgraph(javax.persistence.metamodel.Attribute<T,X>)`

But how can I create EntityGraph programmably and type-safely using JPA static MetaModel in these case ?

### Workaround

```
/**
 * fetch comments and each of comment's author.
 */
public static final Function<EntityManager, EntityGraph<Article>> DETAIL = em -> {
    EntityGraph<Article> graph = em.createEntityGraph(Article.class);

    Subgraph<Comment> sgComment =
      graph.addSubgraph(Article_.comments.getName(), Comment.class);

    sgComment.addAttributeNodes(Comment_.author);

    return graph;
  };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, and after doing some research I'm pretty certain this is a flaw in the JPA **API**.

The *implementation* in EclipseLink seems to do the correct thing:

```
public <T> Subgraph<T> addSubgraph(Attribute<X, T> attribute) {
    Class type = attribute.getJavaType();
    if (attribute.isCollection()) {
        type = ((PluralAttribute) attribute).getBindableJavaType();
    }
    return addSubgraph(attribute.getName(), type);
}
```

Notice how the implemetation violates the declaration from the interface when a `PluralAttribute` is given: With `T` of the `Attribute` being a `Collection<something>`, the method does *not* actually return a `Subgraph<Collection<something>>` as declared but an instance of `Subgraph<something>` instead.

To me it looks as though the API is actually broken in that respect, and noone seems to care because probably not many people make use of `EntityGraph`s *and* the static metamodel, though this would be a good thing to do.

Someone should create an issue somewhere to get that part of the API fixed.

My current 'fix' for the problem is a kind of custom `EntityGraphBuilder` which accepts `SingularAttribute<E,X>` and `PluralAttribute<E,?,X>` to allow type safe-ish creation of `EntityGraph`s. Basically, I just have my `EntityGraphElement`s representing an attribute, or node in the tree, and plug them together via type-safe generic methods. This also has the benefit of merging the distinct for-whatever-reason `EntityGraph` and `SubGraph` interfaces under a common API, so that `EntityGraph` representations can be created and used and re-used as subgraphs in other entity graphs.

My solution could probably be applied to the JPA API too, it basically just splits up the

```
<T> Subgraph<T> addSubgraph(Attribute<X, T> attribute)
```

into two methods:

```
<F> EntityGraphElement<F> fetch(SingularAttribute<? super T, F> attr);
```

and

```
<F> EntityGraphElement<F> fetch(PluralAttribute<? super T, ?, F> attr);
```

Update:

Using some generics Voodoo, *one* method is enough:

```
<F, A extends Attribute<? super T, ?> & Bindable<F>> EntityGraphElement<F> fetch(A attribute);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer old question. I Think too, as you said.